# Contar cantidad de clicks en item ListView

Tags: android, android-studio, listview

Estoy intentando contar la cantidad de <kbd>clicks</kbd> que hace una persona sobre un determinado `item` en un `ListView` en ***AndroidStudio*** mostrándolo en un `textview` dentro de la misma lista. 
Por ejemplo, si presiono el `item a`, el contador aumentará conforme a la cantidad de veces que presione el `item a`. 
Si presiono el item b, aumentará el contador del item b y así sucesivamente.
A lo que me refiero específicamente, es que si presiono el item b el contador muestra su valor en el item a y yo quiero que se muestre en el item b. Dejo captura.

```
public class Mozos extends AppCompatActivity{
    AlmacenConexion aC;
    Spinner spinMozo;
    List<String> listaNombres, listacomidas;
    ArrayAdapter<String> adapterSpin;
    ArrayList<Comidas> arrayComidas;
    adaptadorComidas adap;
    ListView lvCom;
    TextView tv;

    ArrayList<Integer> c;

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_mozos);

        //Spinner
        spinMozo=(Spinner)findViewById(R.id.spinMozo);
        aC=AlmacenConexion.getInstance(this);//para que podamos usar los métodos de la clase AlmacenConexion
        listaNombres =new ArrayList<>();//conversion de List a ArrayList
        int tamañoLista =aC.todosMozos().size(); //almacena el tamaño
        listaNombres.add("Mozo");
        for(int i=0;i<tamañoLista;i++){//agregamos los nombres y los almacanamos el la lista
            listaNombres.add(aC.todosMozos().get(i).getNombre());
        }
        adapterSpin = new ArrayAdapter<>(this, R.layout.support_simple_spinner_dropdown_item, listaNombres);//implementamos un adapter con el contexto
        spinMozo.setAdapter(adapterSpin);//cargamos los datos

        //tv


        //ListView
        arrayComidas = new ArrayList<Comidas>();
        lvCom=(ListView)findViewById(R.id.lvCom);
        arrayComidas=aC.llenar_Comidas();
        c = new ArrayList<>();
        for (int i = 0; i < arrayComidas.size(); i++) {
            c.add(0);
        }
        adap= new adaptadorComidas(this, arrayComidas);
        lvCom.setAdapter(adap);
        lvCom.setClickable(true);
        lvCom.setOnItemClickListener(new AdapterView.OnItemClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> parent, View view, int position, long id) {
                tv=(TextView)findViewById(R.id.lbl_cantidad_producto);
                aC = new AlmacenConexion(getApplicationContext());
                int contador = c.get(position);
                contador++;
                c.set(position,contador);
                if(position==0){
                    tv.setText(""+(c.get(position)));
                    System.out.println("position:" + position);
                }else if(position==1){
                    tv.setText(""+(c.get(position)));
                    System.out.println("position:" + position);
                }
            }
        });
    }
}
```

**GIF**

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Y este es el adaptador:

```
public class adaptadorComidas extends BaseAdapter {
    private Context c;
    ArrayList<Comidas> arraComi;

    public adaptadorComidas(Context context, ArrayList<Comidas> comidas){
        this.c=context;
        this.arraComi=comidas;
    }

    @Override
    public int getCount(){
        return this.arraComi.size();
    }
    @Override
    public Object getItem(int position){
        return this.arraComi.get(position);
    }
    @Override
    public long getItemId(int position){
        return  position;
    }

    @Override
    public View getView(int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent) {
        //creamos la vista
        View rowView = convertView;
        if (convertView == null) {
            // Nueva vista en la lista
            LayoutInflater inflater = (LayoutInflater) c
                    .getSystemService(Context.LAYOUT_INFLATER_SERVICE);
            rowView = inflater.inflate(R.layout.item_list_general, parent, false);//La metemos en el layout
            //Que es una vista creada
        }
        // Mostramos los datos
        TextView nombreProducto= rowView.findViewById(R.id.lbl_nombre_producto); //en un textview
        TextView precioProducto= rowView.findViewById(R.id.lbl_precio_producto); //en un textview

        Comidas comidas = this.arraComi.get(position); //llamamos a la clase según la posición
        nombreProducto.setText(comidas.getDescr());//traemos los valores a mostrar
        precioProducto.setText(comidas.getPre());//traemos los valores a mostrar

        return rowView;
    }
```

Hasta ahora, esto solo funciona con el primer item de la lista. Es decir, tengo el item a y al presionar sobre él va aumentando el contador. Pero, si presiono el `item b` de la lista sigue aumentando el contador del `item a.`

Comment: Es normal que haga eso si siempre estas haciendo el c++ sin importar la opción que haga click...

Comment: El position sirve para asignar la posición a la cual estoy asignando el c++

Comment: El problema no es el position sino que el contador donde almacenas deberías tener uno por cada position para que no se acumule todo en el mismo

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Podrias crear un array de contadores, y cada vez que presiones un `item` actualizas el contador de esa posicion.

Tu ***Array*** de contadores:

```
ArrayList<Integer> c;
```

Inicializas tu ***array*** de contadores de acuerdo a la cantidad de `items` que tengas:

```
c = new ArrayList<>();
for (int i = 0; i < arrayComidas.size(); i++) {
  c.add(0);
}
```

Cuando hagan <kbd>Click</kbd> en el item actualizas el contador de esa posicion con

```
  int contador = c.get(position);
  contador++;
  c.set(position,contador);
```

y cambias el textview con

```
tv.setText(""+(c.get(position));
```

Al final tu codigo quedaria masomenos asi con los cambios sugeridos:

```
public class Mozos extends AppCompatActivity{
    AlmacenConexion aC;
    Spinner spinMozo;
    List<String> listaNombres, listacomidas;
    ArrayAdapter<String> adapterSpin;
    ArrayList<Comidas> arrayComidas;
    adaptadorComidas adap;
    ListView lvCom;
    TextView tv;

    ArrayList<Integer> c;

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_mozos);

        //Spinner
        spinMozo=(Spinner)findViewById(R.id.spinMozo);
        aC=AlmacenConexion.getInstance(this);//para que podamos usar los métodos de la clase AlmacenConexion
        listaNombres =new ArrayList<>();//conversion de List a ArrayList
        int tamañoLista =aC.todosMozos().size(); //almacena el tamaño
        listaNombres.add("Mozo");
        for(int i=0;i<tamañoLista;i++){//agregamos los nombres y los almacanamos el la lista
            listaNombres.add(aC.todosMozos().get(i).getNombre());
        }
        adapterSpin = new ArrayAdapter<>(this, R.layout.support_simple_spinner_dropdown_item, listaNombres);//implementamos un adapter con el contexto
        spinMozo.setAdapter(adapterSpin);//cargamos los datos

        //tv


        //ListView
        arrayComidas = new ArrayList<Comidas>();
        lvCom=(ListView)findViewById(R.id.lvCom);
        arrayComidas=aC.llenar_Comidas();
        c = new ArrayList<>();
        for (int i = 0; i < arrayComidas.size(); i++) {
            c.add(0);
        } 
        adap= new adaptadorComidas(this, arrayComidas);
        lvCom.setAdapter(adap);
        lvCom.setClickable(true);
        lvCom.setOnItemClickListener(new AdapterView.OnItemClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> parent, View view, int position, long id) {
                tv=(TextView)findViewById(R.id.lbl_cantidad_producto);
                aC = new AlmacenConexion(getApplicationContext());
                int contador = c.get(position);
                contador++;
                c.set(position,contador);
                tv.setText(""+(c.get(position));

            }
        });
```

Comment: Gracias, pero sigue sucediendo lo mismo. Si presiono el item b el contador sigue aumentando en el item a

Comment: estas capturando el click correctamente? prueba colocando para ver en el logcal `System.out.println("position:" + position);` o muestralo en el textview con `tv.setText("" + position);`

Comment: Creo que yo me estoy expresando mal. No es que el contador sume los clicks de a +b, sino que al presionar el item b, el textview se setea en el item a. Deja, modificaré la pregunta

Comment: tambien puedes subir capturas de pantalla para entender mejor tu problematica

Comment: De hecho, actualicé la pregunta y puse un gif para que se entendiera lo que intento decir

Comment: al parecer es un problema con tu adaptador, el tv no deberia estar en esta clase, sino que en el click deberias setearlo directamente , algo asi como `TextView tv = view.tv; tv.setText("" + c.get(position))`, puedes tambien subir el codigo de tu adaptadorComidas. No puedo comentar en tu pregunta asi que lo hago aqui :)

Comment: [Continuemos el debate en el chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/97885/discussion-between-wilmer-and-franqo-balsamo).